# parse JSON from url using Eniro search API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to use an external API from eniro http://api.eniro.com/ for my rails application.

They have provided a code snippet to use for ruby as a working example, but I need further assist on how I can use it. The code below is my controller.

My Controller

```
class ListanController < ApplicationController

  require 'open-uri' 
  require 'rubygems' 
  require 'json' 

  def get_json  
@json = JSON.parse( open('http://api.eniro.com/partnerapi/cs/search/basic?profile=[*******]&key=[**********]&country=se&version=1.1.3&search_word=pizza').read ) 
@json['adverts'].each do |advert| 
puts advert['companyInfo']['companyName'] 
end
end

def index
    @json = JSON.parse(open('http://api.eniro.com/cs/search/basic?profile=mrshawn191&key=5582158511111471396&country=se&version=1.1.3&search_word=pizza').read ) 
end

end
```

My view

```
<h1><center>Test site</center></h1>

<center>
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :index, params[:index] %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
</center>

<% @json['adverts'].each do |advert| %>
  <%= advert['companyInfo']['companyName'] %>
<% end %>
```

How do I interact with this controller in my view?

I want simply to create a search form in my view that is connected to the external API, so whenever I search for something it will redirect me to a new page and display the result from the api.I don't know much but what I'm guessing is that I have to

- In my controller, specify a method where I parse url into json object
- In my view puts that json objekt? depending on what the keyword is?
- Configure routes.rb to match the search path

I'm lost, can anyone give any guidelines where to start? How would the code look in my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code parts

```
@json['adverts'].each do |advert| 
  puts advert['companyInfo']['companyName'] 
end
```

merely print it to the console. Since you want it showing in your view, you can just remove those.

In your view (if you're using ERB), add

```
<% @json['adverts'].each do |advert| %>
  <%= advert['companyInfo']['companyName'] %>
<% end %>
```

which should then do the same as your `puts`code, just for the HTML rendered on page. Format as appropriate.

Comment: should my index method in controller be left empty?

Comment: The `@json = JSON.parse( open(...))` line is still required, as otherwise `@json` won't be set.

Comment: I have updated my code but im getting error "OpenURI::HTTPError in ListanController#index" I have updated my code could you spot the error?

Comment: That's a standard HTTP Error code, what's the associated message?

Comment: Ok it was my bad I corrected the URL. Now it works. I get all the results for "pizza" because that is defined in controller as an example. How do I do so that the results depends on the parameter typed in the search form? how do I connect my search form to the query?

Comment: You can use `URI::encode(params[:parameter_name])` - the `URI::encode` is necessary cause you want to pass it on to an external resource.

Comment: is URI::escape the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, one is an alias for the other.